# DC Motor used in cordless drill - is it polarity-sensitive?

Tags: dc-motor

I have an old cordless drill  I've stripped the motor out of. Am I correct in saying all dc motor aren't polarity sensitive? I thought that how you reverse the direction of the motor

Comment: Technically the DC motor isn't "cordless" - but the device you removed it from was. So I think I'd omit "cordless" from the description of the motor itself (in the title).

Comment: The word "cordless" accurately describes the motor he is dealing with.  Especially because it means it is probably a bit smaller than a wired drill.  Also cordless instantly implies DC.

Comment: @portforwardpodcast Just to clarify, I edited his title to respond to JYelton's observation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All permanent magnet motors are polarity sensitive. Some DC (also called **universal**) motors have a stator winding rather than a PM .. they run in the same direction regardless of input voltage polarity. To reverse that kind of motor you have to reverse **one** of the windings. The latter kind of motor is not very common in cordless power tools.

Edit: Given the additional information that this is a Dewalt drill, [here](http://www.ereplacementparts.com/images/dewalt/DC759KA_Type_1.pdf) is a typical exploded diagram.

[image]

We're getting off-topic here, and well into repair territory, but looking at the diagram you can see the gearbox/clutch (14), the motor (13), which appears to be a brushed permanent-magnet motor, and the switch-speed controller assembly (9). Applying DC voltage to the motor (13) leads (disconnected from (9)!!- "stripped out" as you said originally) and it should run forward or backward, unless the brushes are worn out or it's otherwise damaged.

Applying reverse voltage to the input of what DeWalt sometimes calls a "VSR Switch" (9) will likely damage that module- there's a lot more than a "switch" in there. Applying voltage of either polarity to the motor with it still connected to the output of (9) might well damage the module. As Russell says, the default in design would **not** be to add cost to every unit in order to protect against this sort of thing.

Brushes are cheap (maybe $5), and they do wear out (with similar symptoms to what you describe), so maybe that was all that was wrong (is wrong) with the motor, so perhaps you need new brushes (and now the VSR Switch (maybe $50)).

Video on replacing DeWalt motor brushes: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tECeZi6IfvU

The VSR switch (9) is a non-repairable module integrated with the trigger switch.

Comment: Well the dewalt stopped working. It kept randomly loosing power. When I observed the correct polarity whilst connected to 18v dewalt from different drill nothing happened. I reversed it and it fried my test leads. Have I let out the smoke then because now when I connect it observing polarity it just gives me load in f blue sparks.

Comment: Reversing the voltage to an electronic speed controller could well be terminal.

Comment: Ok it's a new motor then lol. nextime I 'll try not to be a smart ass and ask first

Comment: Am trying to myself feel better. I have disconnected the motor from the trigger. It's just the motor and it's supply leads now. Soldered wires to the spade connector. I t did rotate slightly once now it's completely dead. Did I kill motor or was the motor already dead?  But this begs the question why it didn't work when I wired the battery correctly to the terminals. I know this because it didn't let out magic smoke. Where as it did when swapped it over

Comment: See my above comments in the edit. This is completely off topic now, so this will have to be it, but you've got something to work with. If you need something to feel better, it's inexpensive "tuition" when you're learning something new, as long as you learn.

Comment: Thanks for yout help spehro pefhany. AFAIK the motor is fine. THe brushes are a little short for the cheap springy metal to make good contact with the commutator. Everytime I push it down with my insulated screwdirver the motor spins then stops when I let go. I have ordered new brushes from an authorised dealer. ALso a vsr switch which I stupidly blown. I always learn from expensive mistakes lool

Answer (score 2):

A typical "brush"* electric drill **MOTOR** will reverse direction with polarity BUT if you apply reversed polarity to the assembled drill's battery terminals it may emit magic smoke or behave erratically. This is because the typical **speed controller** which is activated by the finger switch expects a standard polarity only and the speed control transistor and associated circuitry does not "expect" battery reversal. Drill direction reversal is usually achieved by a mechanical double pole double throw centre off switch incorporated in the speed controller and activated by the side to side motion of the finger operated direction selector. More modern drills MAY use a full electronic H bridge to achieve the same result but still would not 'expect' the battery polarity to be reversed.

*Most cordless drills use DC "brush" motors with a commutator.
The rotor is a wound electromagnet and the stator is a ring of permanent magnets (often a single ring with multiple sequential NSNSN... poles formed on it.)
The commutator and brushes form a mechanical switch which arranges the rotor fields to "point" in desired directions to cause desired direction or rotation for a given polarity. If you reverse the input polarity you reverse the field directions in all cases and, as the stator fields are produced by permanent magnets and cannot reverse, the net interactions are reversed in direction and all forces produced are reversed in direction.
So, the motor direction reverses.

Many modern devices (but very few cordless drills) use "brushless motors" which usually use a 3 phase set of stator coils and a permanent magnet rotor and so do not need or have a commutator. An electronic controller (the "ESC" = Electronic Speed Controller" of RC model terminology) is interposed between the power connections and the motor proper so how the motor responds to polarity is entirely dependent on the controller design. 
An ESC could be designed, when polarity is reversed, to: reverse direction, maintain direction, not produce rotation in one polarity or emit magic smoke. The last is the default state.

Answer (score 1):

You should try and see what happens, there is almost no change of damaging the motor.  Especially if you use the original battery.

Some smaller motors, especially the micro ones used in toy helicopters are meant to only spin in one direction.  Applying reverse voltage will make it spin backwards, but there isn't as much torque in that direction.